# How to efficiently design database of multi list application

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I apologize for the verbosity but I'm trying to reach a design for a sample application I am working on. Below I've explained an **Example** case, **Desired Queries** for the example case, and my **DB design**

I am looking for suggestions on how to improve my current design that'll enable me to answer the queries I have in the example section.

**Example:**

Scenario:

- *John* creates two topics Math, and Science

  - Adds items calculus & algebra to Math, and Physics to Science
- *James* creates two topics Math, and Music

  - Adds items pre-calc to Math, and Rock to Music
- *Lisa* creates two topics Math, and CompSci

  - Adds items Linear Algebra to Math, and Java to CompSci
- *John* shares his item calculus from topic Math with *James*

  - *James* accepts the item
  - *James* shares the same item with *Lisa*
  - *Lisa* accepts the item

**Desired Queries:**

*John*

- List of topics and count of items in each will show:

  - Math - 2, Science - 1
- List of items in Math will show each items' share count and who shared it

  - Calculus - 2 - you, Algebra - 0 - NULL

*James*

- List of topics and count of items in each will show:

  - Math - 2, Music - 1
- List of items in Math will show each items' share count and who shared it

  - Calculus - 2 - James, Pre-Calc - 0 - NULL

*Lisa*

- List of topics and count of items in each will show:

  - Math - 2, CompSci - 1
- List of items in Math will show each items' share count and who shared it

  - Calculus - 2 - James, Linear Algebra - 0 - NULL

**Current DB Design**

User:

```
ID     username
----   ----------
1        John
2        James
3        Lisa
```

Topics

```
ID      Topic_Name      User_id
---     ---------       --------
1        Math           1
2        Science        1
3        Math           2
4        Music          2
5        Math           3
6        CompSci        3
```

Items

```
ID     Item_Name        Topic_Id
---   ----------       ----------
1      Calculus           1
2      Algebra            1
3      Physics            2
4      Pre-Calc           3
5      Rock               4
6      Linear Algebra     5
7      Java               6
```

Share

```
ID   Item_Id    Sent_user_id    Accepted_user_id
---  -------   -------------    -----------------
1     1          1                 2
1     1          1                 3
```

To me the above DB design makes sense but I'm having trouble getting the query results I want. I'm not sure whether my queries can be improved or I should change my design to be better suited for my desired queries

Query 1: Get Topics and their item count BY USERID

```
-- This only works for certain cases
SELECT t.topic_name, count(topic_name) as item_count
FROM Topics t
INNER JOIN Items i on i.topic_id = t.id
INNER JOIN User on u.id = t.user_id
INNER JOIN Share s on s.item_id = i.id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY t.topic_name
```

The above query returns following for *John*

```
topic_name      item_count
-----------    ------------
Math              3
Science           1
```

But it *should* return the following for *John*

```
topic_name      item_count
-----------    ------------
Math              2
Science           1
```

should return following for *James*

```
topic_name      item_count
-----------    ------------
Math              2
Music             1
```

should return following for *Lisa*

```
topic_name      item_count
-----------    ------------
Math                2
CompSci             1
```

Note that `item_count` should be 2 for *James*. I believe the above query works fine for other users.

Query 2: Get items and their shared count and who originally shared them BY USERID

```
   --I'm not sure how to start on this. I've tried union with Items table and Share table
   -- but that also works only for few users and not for all cases.
```

for *John* for Math I would expect:

```
Item Name    Share Count     Orig Shared By
---------    -----------    -----------------
Calculus       2              You
Algebra        0              NULL
```

For James for Math:

```
Item Name    Share Count     Orig Shared By
---------    -----------    -----------------
Calculus        2              James
Pre-Calc        0              NULL
```

For Lisa for Math:

```
Item Name         Share Count     Orig Shared By
---------         -----------    -----------------
Calculus              2              James
Linear Algebra        0              NULL
```

**Update**

Based on the comments and answer I've changed the DB Schema a bit. I've made a separate join table which establishes the relationship between Users-Topics-Items.

Please see this sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15211/15

But I still need help with the queries. I feel like I'm close.

Comment: Why do you feel that your current design is not efficient? And what are you hoping to gain? Just curious.

Comment: I'm looking to get an answer to the two queries which will answer the questions for each user. I think the current design is not up to par because I'm having a tough time coming up with query to both my questions. 1) Get topics for each user including the count of items in each (including shared count) e.g. James Sub-bullet one 2) Get the shared count for each item including the shared count e.g. James Sub-bullet two

Comment: I've edited the query I'm trying to give more insight.

Comment: I would change you design in some things. 1 - I would make the Topics table with uique topics; 2-I would do the same for itens. Itens would be unique and I would have a table n-m between Itens and Topics (Cauculus could be Math or Science since Physics is an item). Finally I would have an N-M table between itemTopics and Users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your design should be normalized a bit more:

Users:

```
Id     username
----   ----------
1        John
2        James
3        Lisa
```

Topics:

```
Id      Topic_Name
---     ---------
1        Math
2        Science
3        Music
4        CompSci
```

SubTopics:

```
Id    SubTopic_Name    Topic_Id
---   ----------       --------
1      Calculus           1
2      Algebra            1
3      Physics            2
4      Pre-Calc           1
5      Rock               3
6      Linear Algebra     1
7      Java               4
```

That way, you start with users and Topics/SubTopics being orthogonal sets — completely unrelated, if you prefer. From there, then toss in new fields and/or relationships to connect them per your use-case.

You seem to need to track permissions. There are many ways to store permission-related data. For inspiration, look into ACL (access control lists) and RBAC (role-based access control) in particular. (If you're using PHP, look into the Symfony or Yii frameworks for implementation ideas.)

Speaking personally, I'd advise to track ownership using an entirely separate table, rather than using an owner_id in SubTopics: you never know when you might want shared ownership of a node in the future.

For the sake of simplifying your example, though, we'll add an owner_id field regardless, and stick to a simplistic permissions table:

SubTopics becomes:

```
Id    SubTopic_Name    Topic_Id    Owner_Id
---   -------------    --------    --------
1      Calculus           1           1
2      Algebra            1           1
3      Physics            2           1
4      Pre-Calc           1           2
5      Rock               3           2
6      Linear Algebra     1           3
7      Java               4           3
```

SubTopic_Access:

```
User_Id  SubTopic_Id
--—----  --—------—-
   1          1            # John created Calculus
   1          2     
   1          3     
   2          4            # James created Pre-Calc
   2          5     
   3          6            # Lisa created Linear Algebra
   3          7     
   2          1            # James accepted Calculus
   3          1            # Lisa accepted Calculus
```

(The benefit of tossing all users that have access, including owners, in the latter table is to simplify queries down the road.)

If you need to track invites outside of emails, either toss the invites in a different "Invites" table, or add a field in the above table if you don't mind carting `Is_Active = 1` clauses all over the place. (Fwiw, the latter is tedious unless you're using views, and not so great for indexes.)

Your first query seems to be counting the number of subtopics a user has access to in each topic. A starting point could be this:

```
select s.Topic_Id, count(s.Id)
from SubTopics s
join SubTopic_Access a
  on a.SubTopic_Id = s.Id
where a.User_id = ?
group by s.Topic_Id
```

Your second query seems to be counting the number of *other* users who can access a subtopic a user has access to. (I likewise imagine that Orig Shared By should actually display John each time.) A starting point count be this:

```
select s.Id, count(o.User_Id), s.Owner_id
from SubTopics s
join SubTopic_Access a
  on a.SubTopic_Id = s.ID
left join SubTopic_Access o
  on o.SubTopic_Id = s.ID
 and o.User_id <> a.User_Id
where s.Topic_Id = ?
  and a.User_id = ?
group by s.Id, s.Owner_id
```

(In the above, the Owner_Id field will always be populated. You could use NullIf on it to nullify the value where needed if needed.)

Answer (score 3):

With new design as:
[image]

> Query 1: Get Topics and their item count BY USERID

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, T.Topic_Name ,   
(
  (SELECT count(*) FROM UserTopicItem
   WHERE UserTopicItem.topic_id= t.id
   AND   UserTopicItem.user_id = UTI.user_id)
  +
  (SELECT count(*) FROM Shares
   WHERE Shares.Topic_id = UTI.Topic_id
   AND Shares.Accepted_user_id = u.id)
) AS item_count
FROM UserTopicItem UTI
INNER JOIN USERS u ON u.id = UTI.user_id
INNER JOIN topics T ON T.id = UTI.Topic_Id
-- where u.id = ?
ORDER BY u.username;
```

> Query 2: Get items and their shared count and who originally shared
>   them BY USERID

```
SELECT i.item_name, t.topic_name
,(SELECT count(*) FROM shares 
  WHERE shares.Item_Id = i.id
  and shares.user_id   = u.id
  and shares.topic_id  = t.id
 ) AS shared_count
,decode((SELECT count(*) FROM shares 
  WHERE shares.Item_Id = i.id
  and shares.user_id   = u.id
  and shares.topic_id  = t.id
 ),0,'Null',u.username) AS Orig_Shared_By 
FROM UserTopicItem UTI 
INNER JOIN Items i  ON UTI.item_id = i.id
INNER JOIN topics t ON UTI.topic_id = t.id
INNER JOIN Users u  ON UTI.user_id = u.id
-- where u.id = ?
order by u.id,shared_count desc;
```

[**sqlfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71072c/6)

Comment: Thanks. But query one has the same problem I was having. For _James_ the count for Math should be 2 because he has Pre-calc and Calculus (which was shared to him by another User). I've updated the question with desired query results for each scenario, please take a look. I think for query one, share table will also need to be queried.

Comment: This schema is still problematic. You shouldn't really have a Topics table which has entries like 'Math' duplicated per user. Also, can your Items belong to more than one Topic? For example, 'Physics' can be Math and Science.

Comment: @Patrick i updated the answer, also ChrisLava comment is totally correct.

Comment: @ChrisLava I hadn't thought about the item belonging to multiple topics. But that makes sense. In the future I would like the flexibility to allow that. I knew the schema wasn't where it should be when I started writing union queries and such. Any guidance on schema?

Comment: @MohsenHeydari Thanks! I am looking at the results now. I will create new sqlfiddle with the hints you provided

Comment: @MohsenHeydari Based on your hints I've modified the DB Schema. Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15211/8 But I still need help with the queries...

Comment: 2 hints: 1- user-topic-item dos not need surrogate id as pk, FKs will be the pk, accepted? If accepted Shared table structure will be more meaning full. accept or reject the hints then i will help you for the queries.

Comment: 1 - accepted, it doesn't need a separate ID column as pk. But I'm still having problem getting topics and their counts (including shared) for users. Do I need to union the two tables? This is where I'm at so far: sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15211/19

Comment: updated schema with your suggestion: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cbfe/3 but query results are still skewed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43063/discussion-between-mohsen-heydari-and-patrick)